# Choosing Stack Exchange site for general geography questions

Tags: support

Is there any Stack Exchange site for geography questions that don't fit here because they don't require or make use of GIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earth Science Stack Exchange has (at the time of writing) [156 geography questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/geography), so your question might fit there (or already be asked). The topic isn't listed in the site's [Help Center](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but [it seems the community is OK with them](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1743/2958).